# AttributeError: module 'tweepy.streaming' has no attribute 'StreamListener'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy to monitor a user and I'm using the stream element, but I got this error

```
AttributeError: module 'tweepy.streaming' has no attribute 'StreamListener'
```

This are the import:

```py
import tweepy
from tweepy import streaming
```

I also tried importing:

```py
from tweepy.streaming import Stream
```

This is my code:

```py
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.streaming.StreamListener):
    

    def on_status(self, status):
        webhook.send(status.text)
        # SMS.send(status.text)
        print(status.text)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_error disconnects the stream
            return False

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
# edit with the twitter IDs as needed
myStream.filter(follow=["twitter id"],is_async=True)
```

Comment: If you are using Tweepy v4, the `StreamListener` is no more.   https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/changelog.html#version-4-0-0

Answer (score 1):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) merged `StreamListener` into `Stream`.
I recommend updating your code to subclass [`Stream`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.1.0/stream.html) instead.
Alternatively, you can downgrade to v3.10.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `StreamListener` was merged into `Stream` in [Tweepy v4.0.0](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.14.0/changelog.html#version-4-0-0-2021-09-25), almost two years ago, and `Stream` was removed in [Tweepy v4.14.0](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.14.0/changelog.html#version-4-14-0-2023-04-24), as `streaming` with Twitter API v1.1 has been deprecated.

`tweepy.Stream` was a class, not an attribute, and `tweepy.stream` never existed.

If you want to use `streaming`, you'll have to use [Twitter API v2 with StreamingClient](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.14.0/streaming.html#using-streamingclient) and Pro or Enterprise access.